# Activity com.ui.MapViewer has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow that was originally added here

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-camera, android-popupwindow

I'm doing a android map where i have a map with some points using mapsforge and every point on the map is saved in a spatialite database. After that, every click on the map opens a custom PopUp window, that receive the current activity as context, with all the information about the point available to be edited and updated on the database. Now, i've added a button to the popup window with name "Take Photo" that when is clicked do the following:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(mapViewer.getPackageManager()) != null) {
takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
mapViewer.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
}
```

And after i take the photo and save them is supposed return to my previous map activity with the popup window opened like before i click in the button Take Photo inside popup window but i receive the follow error:

> E/WindowManager(15089): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity
>   com.ui.MapViewer has leaked window
>   android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupViewContainer@4281bc98 that was
>   originally added here

Why this is happens? I can't understand! After that i try to create my custom activity implementing the camera api with only a button to take a photo and after that start this activity from my popup window and after take the photo call the finish() of the activity and in this way i don't receive any error. However this is not a solution for me because i need zoom and flash in my camera app.

My implementation of popup window are in the follow pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/9hHgSrUH

Anyone can help me solving this serious problem?

Best Regards

**EDIT:** I've detected that onDestroy of the activity in the stack is called when i click save after take the picture. But why is destroyed called? I'm not calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably is the camera app that change your screen orientation after take the photo and your main activity are destroyed and created again.

Try to do

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```